# Eclipse EclEmma missed instructions

Tags: eclipse, code-coverage, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, emma

I'm using Eclipse-STS + EclEmma plugin to see coverage of my code. In all my abstract util classes (with only static methods) I see 3 missed instructions (`Instructions Counter` report) at the class definition line:

[image]

No marker available at the left of the red line, so I do not know exactly what are these instructions. Maybe some constructors? What can I do to cover them?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but I am curious as to why this is so important to you.  Are you required to get 100% coverage?  IMO, coverage tools like Emma are best at signifying weak spots in your testing. If you know these instructions are covered, but emma doesn't show it, that is not a problem with your tests (although it may indicate a bug in emma).

Comment: I'm just a perfectionist and want to see that cherished number in reports. Also, I'm just curious.

Comment: I get it. :-)  Wish I had an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I found to achieve 100% covering is to write a test method like this:

```
@Test
public void coverage(){
    KeyEscaper a = new KeyEscaper() {
    };
}
```

As soon as the issue touches only utils classes with all static methods, it's not a problem to instantiate them anonimously in such way.

Comment: Just doing a `new KeyEscaper();` should be enough.
Also, you could put it in a static method with `@BeforClass` so you don't have to create a dummy test.

Comment: Cannot do `new`, as the class is abstract.

Comment: You can combine the two approaches though (anonymous subclass, but without local variable) by simply `new KeyEscaper() {};`.